# From Windows Threading Libraries to C++11

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I want to remove some Windows dependencies in how the threading is done in an old code, how can I convert this piece of code to C++11 threading style?

MyClass run Method:

```
void MyClass::run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(startEvent, INFINITE);

        processData();

        ResetEvent(startEvent);
        SetEvent(hEvent);
    }
}
```

Main Update in another class:

```
{
    .
    .
    .
    WaitForSingleObject(myClassInstance.hEvent, INFINITE);
    ResetEvent(myClassInstance.hEvent);

    // Getting data processed by myClassInstance in the previous update call
    // Mem copies to myClassInstance to be used later by myClassInstance processData()

    SetEvent(myClassInstance.startEvent);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an event class easily with `std::condition_variable` and a `bool`:

```
class Event {
  std::condition_variable cv_;
  std::mutex mtx_;
  bool signaled_ = false;

public:
  void wait() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx_};
    while (!signaled_) {
      cv_.wait(lock);
    }
  }

  void reset() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mtx_};
    signaled_ = false;
  }

  void set() {
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mtx_};
      signaled_ = true;
    }
    cv_.notify_one();
  }
};
```

Resulting in the usage:

```
struct MyClass {
  Event start;
  Event ready;

  void processData();
  void run();
};

void MyClass::run() {
  while (true) {
    start.wait();

    processData();

    start.reset();
    ready.set();
  }
}

void main_update_in_another_class() {
  ready.wait();
  ready.reset();

  // Getting data processed by myClassInstance in the previous update call
  // Mem copies to myClassInstance to be used later by myClassInstance processData()

  start.set();

  // Do other things that don't require access to myClassInstance
}
```

**[See the live demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8492c3d556d1ffac)**.

Comment: Aweson Casey, it works perfectly, I thought that it would be a bit more complex but in reality is not, you just have to know how the C++11 threading library works, thanks! (sorry, can't vote for your answer I need 15 points of reputation!)